# 4bit demultiplexer with address entries in the EXCESS-3 code

Tags: multiplexer, binary, code

[image]

My question is: how to make truth table for inputs on E3? There is only space for 2 bits, and E3 is written on 4 bits as I saw. Should I add more inputs for this situation or do this in different way?

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear but if you have 4 output states, you only need 2 bit input because 2^2 = 4, so that's enough. Hope that answers [image]

Comment: Thank you! But I have a problem with putting EXCESS-3 code on 2 inputs? How it will look like?

Comment: i have edited the answer